# Creating a tree structure with dict and lists in Python for QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qtreewidget

First of all Im out of practice and Im trying to create a tree structure in Python 3.8 to feed my QTreeView.

I read the output of zfs (subprocess.check_output) and split the whole stuff to have a list with pool names:

Example list:

```
pools = ['deadpool','deadpool/Backup','deadpool/Photos','deadpool/Photos/Foobar']
```

Now I've to convert and sort the whole list by parent/child and it should look like this at the end so I can use it in a QTreeView:

```
{'deadpool': 
            {
              'Backup': {},
              'Photos': {'Foobar': {}},
            } 
}
```

I tried it with two for loops but Im just too stupid..

Can someone show me an easy example?

Or is there an easier way in QtTreeView/QTreeWidget itself?

Comment: pyqt5 or pyside2?

Comment: PyQt5.

Whats the easiest elegant way to fill  QTreeView or QTreeWidget idc which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want to build a treewidget from a dict ? If it is, this is a very quick example with Pyside2 (I think there is no problem with PyQt5 for the Treewidget).

```
data = {
'deadpool':{
    'Backup': {},
    'Photos': {
        'Foobar': {}
        }
    }
}

def build_tree(data=None, parent=None):
    for key, value in data.items():
        item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
        item.setText(0, key)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            build_tree(data=value, parent=item)


window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
window.setLayout(layout)
treewidget = QTreeWidget()
build_tree(data=data, parent=treewidget)
layout.addWidget(treewidget)
window.show()
```

If you just want convert your list to the dict in order to use it in the treewidget you can try this:

```
data = ['deadpool','deadpool/Backup','deadpool/Photos','deadpool/Photos/Foobar']

tree = {}
for path in data:                # for each path
    node = tree                   # start from the very top
    for level in path.split('/'): # split the path into a list
        if level:                 # if a name is non-empty
            node = node.setdefault(level, dict())
                              # move to the deeper level
                              # (or create it if unexistent)

print(tree)
```

This code above is from this topic : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971687/creating-nested-dictionaries-from-a-list-containing-paths)

And now your have a dict to use with the fisrt bloc of code !

I hope it will help you !

Comment: That's it!

Thank you so much :)